# How apply CSS only to my custom WordPress shortcode?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I'm writing my second WordPress plugin, I successfully enqueued JavaScript and CSS (Bootstrap) to backend settings page. Now, to interact with frontend, I want to create some shortcodes using Bootstrap.
How can I use Bootstrap (and other custom CSS and JavaScript) only in my shortcodes without affecting style of the pages that will use the shortcodes?

Comment: you can give your own class to the` shortcode` ad and target the element using that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a div-container around your content with a unique class name.

```
function shortcode_func(){
  return '<div class="your-unique-shortcode-class">...</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'your-shortcode', 'shortcode_func' );
```

Than you can add your stylesheet with the `wp_enqueue_style` function.

```
function shortcode_footer_func() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'shortcode_styles', 'your/path/to/style.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'shortcode_footer_func' );
```